# Insect Identification: What's this insect

Tags: compost, insects

Recently i found an insect very rapidly multiplying itself in the compost heap at home. I took some blurry images of the insect since they were very brisk and not sufficiently static. I am concerned on their numbers getting multiplied in the compost. Kindly help in identifying this critter and any damage that they can cause to the plants if the compost is applied. Apologies for such pictures!!

[image: Image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The photos are a bit blurry but to me looks like some kind of [earwig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig)

Earwigs typically feed on live sprouts or decaying vegetation and, in rare cases, some species are predators.They prefer dark and wet areas and like to live and lay their eggs there.

I am leaving this link here about [what do they eat](https://www.orkin.com/other/earwigs/what-do-earwigs-eat/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a (very speedy) earwig! Earwigs love damp, close quarters, so I'm sure the compost heap was the perfect home in their eyes. They also do eat both living (plants and small arthropods) and dead organic matter.

If you let the compost dry out a bit and aerate it well before application, I think the risk of earwig damage to your garden plants would be minimal.